# Hover function and rendering not working as expected for overlay on image

Tags: css

I'd like my image to show an overlay upon hover that 1. is same size/dimension 2. has a bg color with opacity and 3. shows text. I am using the below CSS, but the overlay (my-work-overlay) class is showing by default with no hover activity, even though my parent div 'my-work-preview' should be. Providing my Custom CCS + html on page.

I checked my class names multiple times, and the code looks right to me, my-work-overlay displays by default instead of on hover.

CSS

```css
.my-work-preview {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .my-work-image {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
     border-radius: 25px;
    }
    .my-work-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0.8;
      transition: .5s ease;
      background-color: #000000;
       border-radius: 25px;
    }
    .my-work-preview:hover .my-work-overlay {
      opacity: .8; border-radius: 25px;
    }
    .my-work-text {
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: sofia-pro;
      font-style: bold;
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <a href="http://www.theyummyheart.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="my-work-preview">
        <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5d35e760a6e4d600012adfba/t/5d72a84d4d671305694b4763/1567795869852/the-yummy-heart-preview.png?format=500w" alt="The Yummy Heart Preview" class="my-work-image">
          <div class="my-work-overlay">
            <div class="my-work-text"><h3>
              The Yummy Heart
              </h3>Web Design<br>Copy Editing<br>SEO</div>
          </div>
          </div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set opacity `opacity: 0.8;` as a default property on the `div.my-work-preview`, which is causing the hover to not work, disabling the opacity or changing its value to a different value, will fix the issue of hover not working.

```css
.my-work-preview {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .my-work-image {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
     border-radius: 25px;
    }
    .my-work-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: .5s ease;
      background-color: #000000;
       border-radius: 25px;
    }
    .my-work-preview:hover .my-work-overlay {
      opacity: .8; border-radius: 25px;
    }
    .my-work-text {
      color: white;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: sofia-pro;
      font-style: bold;
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <a href="http://www.theyummyheart.com" target="_blank">
          <div class="my-work-preview">
        <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5d35e760a6e4d600012adfba/t/5d72a84d4d671305694b4763/1567795869852/the-yummy-heart-preview.png?format=500w" alt="The Yummy Heart Preview" class="my-work-image">
          <div class="my-work-overlay">
            <div class="my-work-text"><h3>
              The Yummy Heart
              </h3>Web Design<br>Copy Editing<br>SEO</div>
          </div>
          </div></a>
```